# What is the meaning of this error message?

Tags: security, appexchange, security-review

I got an unmanaged package from the developer. I installed it in the developer org. Created a managed package from the components and gave the managed package for security review.

Here is the message that I got:

> The test org provided has the wrong version installed (You submitted
>   version 1.0 but provided version 1.1). Confirm the correct version's
>   installation for testing or otherwise submit the correct version in
>   full.
>
> The test org provided has an unmanaged package installed; you must
>   submit a managed package for security review.

Answer (score 2):

This message probably has to do with the org you've installed managed packaged in. The org has unmanaged package installed. You should create managed package and then submit the org for review.

For this, instead of unmanaged package installation you should move the components from the other org and create a managed package.

You must provide URL of managed package created and not the unmanaged package installed in the org. Also double check the version information provided in security check form is matching with the org you've installed package in.

Comment: I am not very clear on what the suggestion is. Do I need to remove the unmanaged package from the org?